# QASM Files on Jupyter Notebook

Tags: programming, qasm

Is it possible to run qasm files on jupyter notebook (like with the qasm_simulator)?
I downloaded one code file and I would like to play around with it on jupyter notebook.

Comment: This is perhaps a more apt question for the Qiskit communitry https://github.com/qiskit-community

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`QuantumCircuit.from_qasm_str()`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.QuantumCircuit.from_qasm_str.html#qiskit.circuit.QuantumCircuit.from_qasm_str) like this:

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit

qasm_str = """
    OPENQASM 2.0;
    include "qelib1.inc";
    qreg q[2];
    creg c[2];
    h q[0];
    cx q[0],q[1];
    measure q[0] -> c[0];
    measure q[1] -> c[1];
"""

circ = QuantumCircuit.from_qasm_str(qasm_str)
circ.draw('mpl')
```

Comment: Thank you very much